# sms send count more than population

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, sms

[image]

Is it possible that send count are more than node populations?

Answer (score 6):

This is because this is a count of # of messages sent. If the text message exceeds the 160/70 character count it sent as multiple-message

You can review this in the _smsmessagetracking data view